# Creating a contact form in Classic ASP

Tags: html, asp-classic, vbscript, contact-form

I am forced to use Classic ASP for this project and for the most part it hasn't really been a problem for me, until now.  I am not familiar with ASP and all I'm trying to do is create a simple contact form.  Here is my markup:

```
<form method="post" action="contactform_submit.asp">
    <ol class="formset" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
        <li><label for="mbr-y">Are you currently a Walser Rewards Member?</label> <input class="mbr-yn" style="height: 13px; width: 13px" type="radio" name="mbr-y" value="Yes" /> Yes <input class="mbr-yn" style="height: 13px; width: 13px" type="radio" name="mbr-n" value="No" /> No</li>
        <li><label for="fname">Full Name: </label><input id="fname" required="-1" name="fname" type="text" />
        <ol id="member" class="formset" style="padding:0px; margin: 0px;">
            <li><label for="mbrnum">Member Number: </label><input id="mbrnum" name="mbrnum" type="text" /></li>
        </ol>
        </li>
        <li><label for="lname2">Phone Number: </label><input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" /></li>
        <li><label for="email2">Email Address: </label><input id="email" name="email" type="text" /></li>
        <li><label for="message">Message: </label><textarea id="message" required="-1" value="" type="text" name="message"></textarea></li>
    </ol>
    <input style="height: 33px; padding: 0px; margin-top: 7px; width: 120px;" src="/image/walsergold/send-btn.jpg" type="image" />
</form>
```

I have done some research, but it has been difficult for me to interpret how the ASP and HTML interact. I am hoping that if people are talking about my markup, it will be easier for me to understand. Can someone point me in the right direction of how "contactform_submit.asp" will look? Thank you.

EDIT: From my research, I came up with this for "contactform_submit.asp" (it does not work):

```
<%
Dim mail, body

body = "Current Member: " & Request.Form("mbr-yn") & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Member Name: " & Request.Form("fname") & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Member Number: " & Request.Form("mbrnum") & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Phone: " & Request.Form("phone") & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Email: " & Request.Form("email") & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Message: " & Request.Form("message")

Set mail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
mail.To = "email@address.com"
mail.From = "email@address.com"
mail.Subject = "Online Contact Form"
mail.TextBody = body
mail.Send()

Response.Write("Thanks for submitting the feedback. A Customer Service Specialist will be in contact with you shortly.")

Set mail = nothing
Set body = nothing
%>
```

Comment: `mail.From = Request.Form("email")`. you do not have form field named `from`. Does it give any errors, or are you not getting the mail?

Comment: I don't know if you've done this yet, but it's very useful to set-up a custom error reporting page.  [See this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224070).

Comment: Also, just check your server to see if you've got SMTP setup for IIS.  [This page](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e4cf06f5-9a36-474b-ba78-3f287a2b88f2.mspx?mfr=true) shows how to setup for IIS6, but it does depend on your server IIS version.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ sorry, I changed it to how I've been using "To" "From" and "Subject" - It does not send the email and I get this error: "Server Error 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

Comment: @Westie the server looks to be setup with SMTP (based off other files I've seen). Not really sure what that means, though...

Comment: @Travis: Did you try adding the custom error page in?  This might give you a more meaningful error report.  SMTP allows IIS to send mail using a valid email address.  One other thing has crossed my mind - are you using a valid `from` address?

Comment: @Westie The "from" email address is valid. I know next to nothing about asp, and I was unable to add the custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

It will look whatever is in that page i.e. whatever html markup and asp code is. But you can extract the data that are posted to it.

you can use `Dim name = Request.Form("fname")` if you are using vb or

```
string name = Request.Form["fname"]
```

if you are using c#.

Comment: Sorry, I am using VB. I added the asp code that I came up with from doing my research.  Am I even close?

Comment: when you are using `Request.Form("fname")` fname is the `name attribute` of the control. you can use it to pull all the information. As far as sending email is concerned, i don't know how to do that in vb

Comment: @user1: The O.P's not using ASP.NET; it's Classic ASP.  Their `Request.Form` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work on some servers as it is.  On others you may need to use a CDO configuration object.

see here for examples

http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp

Comment: I think you are right.  But I do not know the difference between those and what all needs to be changed.